# Regex for matching any number between 0 to 100?

Tags: perl

I need a regex to match any number between 0 to 100 including decimal numbers example:
my expression should match 1,2,2.3 ,40,40.12 ,100,100.00 like this ..thanks in advance?

Comment: Would't be easier match a number and than compare it to 0 and 100?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011674/how-to-match-a-number-which-is-less-than-or-equal-to-100

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have to allow for a leading sign, you are best off writing

```
if ( /(?<![-+.\d])([-+]?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?![-+.\d])/ and $1 >= 0 and $1 <= 100 ) { .. }
```

But if you are *forced* into using a regex, then you need

```
if ( /(?<![-+.\d])(([-+]?(?:100|\d\d)(?:\.\d*)?(?![-+.\d])/ ) { .. }
```

These pattern may well be more complex than necessary because they allow for the number appearing *anywhere* in the string. If you are simply checking an entire string to see if it matches the criteria then it could be much shorter

Comment: Your regex `/(?<![-+.\d])(([-+]?(?:100|\d\d)(?:\.\d*)?(?![-+.\d])/` is incorrect.  Even after I balanced the parentheses, it behaves incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
(100(\.0+))|([0-9]{1,2}(\.[0-9]+)?)
```

match either "100" (with optional dot plus one or more zeroes) or one or two digits, optionally followed by a dot and at least one digit.

Comment: That matches numbers 100<=x<101

Comment: @justintime - should be fixed now. Good catch.

Comment: This will match `1213215252` as `12 13 21 52 52`.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED!!!

This problem was much more difficult than I initially realized.  With some amount of effort, I have produced a new regex that is without error.  Enjoy.

```
/(?<!\d)(?<!\.)(100(?:(?!\.)|(?:\.0*+|\.))(?=\D)|[0-9]?[0-9](?:\.|\.[0-9]*+)?(?=[\D]))/
```

This pattern will capture in $1

Comment: this will match `199.9999999` which is more than `100`

Comment: M42: I fixed the regex, please retract. :)