# Regular expression between two numeric values

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to match a number which is less than or equal to 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011674/how-to-match-a-number-which-is-less-than-or-equal-to-100)

i need a regular expression between these two values 1000 <= x <= 500000 im trying with this one that i constructed but doesnt seem to work

```
/(1[8-9]|[8-9]|[8-9]|5[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9]|[0-9])/
```

Any ideas? thanks in advance!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/11011934/797393.

Comment: Can't you do this without regex, i.e. exactly as you provided it in your question: `return 1000 <= x && x <= 500000`?

Comment: You have alteration where concatenation is desired.

Answer (score 4):

```
\b([1-9][0-9]{3,4}|[1-4][0-9]{5}|500000)\b
```

Comment: +1, didn't know that *Regex_For_Range* tool!

Comment: Needs to be anchored with `^` and `$`, or e.g. `/([1-9][0-9]{3,4}|[1-4][0-9]{5}|500000)/.test('500000000000000000000000000');  // true`

Comment: The link is infected please don't click on it.

Comment: Thanks @AkashKumarSeth. Removed the link.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a particular reason you don't just test the numbers *as numbers*?

```
var yourNum = parseInt(yourString, 10); // use parseFloat if it has decimals
if (yourNum >= 1000 && yourNum <= 500000) {
    // success
} else 
    // fail
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Match the cases 1000-9999, 10000-99999, 100000-499999 or 500000:

```
([1-9]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{4}|[1-4]\d{5}|500000)
```

Or combining the two first:

```
([1-9]\d{3,4}|[1-4]\d{5}|500000)
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: Perhaps somebody is jealous of your reputation^.^

Comment: Friends don't let friends downvote without commenting!

Comment: Needs to be anchored with `^` and `$`, or e.g. `/([1-9]\d{3,4}|[1-4]\d{5}|500000)/.test('500000000000000000000000000'); // true`

Comment: @MikeM: That depends on what the regular expression is going to be used for. For validation you would naturally have to anchor the pattern, but from the OPs attempt it looks rather like it would be used to capture a value.