# Regex filter the value and show less than required number

Tags: regex

We have the docker  tags with below versions, please help to share the regex pattern to filter the records that is older than below values  for example should show old tags = 123.0.0.187 and older, 123.0.0.187_acme.187.xxxxxxx and older, likewise for others ?

```
123.0.0.188
123.0.0.188_acme.188.xxxxxxx
123.1.0.141
123.1.0.141_acme.141.xxxxxxx
```

I am following this instruction
[how to match a number which is less than or equal to 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011674/how-to-match-a-number-which-is-less-than-or-equal-to-100)

Regex tried :

```
\b(.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.?|188)\b
\b(.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.?|141)\b
```

Comment: What do you mean by "older"? Do you want to match `123.0.0.` and then `188` or less?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^([0-9]+\.){3}(([1-9]{1}[0-8][0-7])|[0-9]{2})(_.+)?$
```

[regexr.com/798l9](https://regexr.com/798l9)